# Trigger a Job if Secret/ConfigMap value changes

Tags: kubernetes

**Expected Behavior**

- Would like to trigger a job if there's a change in the configmap value.

**Problem Statement:**

- Job ensures it creates a secret , the secret value would need to be generated if the config map value changes.
- Job would need to run if there's change in value in the config map.

**Solutions tried -**

- Stakater documentation doesn't support jobs - [Issue for Stakater - Jobs](https://github.com/stakater/Reloader/issues/295)
- Cannot use cronjob as I wouldn't like the job to be triggered on schedule. The condition is that this job is supposed to be triggered only if the config map value changes.
- In Production cluster is locked , cannot use Kubectl/helm upgrade , and cluster can only be managed using ArgoCD Branch.

Environment : K8S
Tools available: ArgoCD
using Helm3

Comment: I might write a custom Kubernetes [operator](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/operator/) that watched the ConfigMap and created the Job.  Deploy-time-only tools like Helm or ArgoCD can't react to live changes in the cluster like this.  If you aren't supposed to directly make changes in the cluster, another approach is to somehow observe the thing that's creating the ConfigMap data and inject an artifical source-control change that would trigger the CD system.

Comment: @Davidmaze stakater reloader is a helm chart that automatically watches a ConfigMap , and i was able to achieve this with the help of reloader .After change detection Reloader performs rolling upgrade on relevant Pods via associated Deployment, Daemonset and Statefulset.
How change detection works Reloader watches changes in configmaps and secrets data. As soon as it detects a change in these. It forwards these objects to an update handler which decides if and how to perform the rolling upgrade. The best part is that it was able to trigger a new job manifest using existing cron manifest.